# Fixing void on face of concrete steps

Tags: concrete, stairs, cement

My front steps are crumbling on the top. I wondered what I could do to fix this? Thanks in advance all!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are many products designed for this type of repair. Most are cement with latex or other additives to improve bond and crack resistance. You'll just need to purchase one and follow the instructions. Look for one that indicates ease of use on vertical surfaces.

You'll probably want a steel trowel of at least 10" in length to achieve a smooth finish.

Comment: I usually drill a few holes and insert galvanized screws in them so they are below the surface this improves holding strngth of the patch when the void is deep.+

Comment: Thank you both! Are galvanized screws the best, or could I use concrete screws?